# error building aurelia application with i18n

Tags: aurelia

I'm converting our `aurelia` project to use `aurelia-cli`.
I added `aurelia-18n, i18n and i18next-xhr-backend` to `aurelia-json` but when I ran `'au build'`, I got error:

```
{ uid: 8,
  name: 'writeBundles',
  branch: false,
  error:
   { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'd:\aurelia\src\relativeTim
e.js']
     errno: -4058,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'open',
     path: 'd:\\aurelia\\src\\relativeTime.js',
     moduleTree: [ 'aurelia-i18n' ],
     fileName: 'd:/aurelia/node_modules/aurelia-i18n/dist/amd/aurelia-i18n.js' }
,
  duration: [ 1, 757878244 ],
  time: 1469807422109 }
```

How do I overcome it? I do not use `relativeTime`, tried to add it but it required `cldr-data` which brought 240Mb to `node_modules` and still had the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've got advice how to configure i18n with aurelia-cli and it worked:

> ```
>     {
>         "name": "aurelia-i18n",
>         "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-i18n/dist/amd",
>         "main": "index"
>       },
>       {
>         "name": "i18next-xhr-backend",
>         "path": "../node_modules/i18next-xhr-backend/dist/umd",
>         "main": "i18nextXHRBackend"
>       },
>       {
>         "name": "i18next",
>         "path": "../node_modules/i18next/dist/umd",
>         "main": "i18next"
>       },
> ```